# Symfony2 : customize form labels in form collections

Tags: doctrine-orm, symfony

I'm trying to customize form labels that are generated in subforms.

I want to display soccer fixtures that are contained in a specific game week, like the following:

```
- Fixture 1 : Manchester United (0) - (1) Arsenal
- Fixture 2 : Chelsea (2) - (1) Liverpool
- ...
```

My form displays all fixtures and related scores but all labels contain the database column names (score1, score2). I want to put team names instead.
So, it currently shows:

```
- Fixture 1 : score1 (0) - (1) score2
- Fixture 2 : score1 (2) - (1) score2
- ...
```

In the controller, I generate the week form (WeekType). $week contains week data and fixtures data using $week->getFixtures().

**Controller/DefaultController.php**

```php
$form = $this->createForm(new WeekType(), $week)->createView();

return array(
    'form' => $form,
);
```

**Form/WeekType.php**

```php
class WeekType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('fixtures', 'collection', array(
            'type' => new FixtureType(),
        ));
    }
 }
```

The Fixture form adds 2 fields. I want to replace default labels into team names.
However I cannot access fixture data in this form. $options is NULL. I thought $options['data'] would contain fixtures data... but I was wrong.

**Form/FixtureType.php**

```php
class FixtureType extends AbstractType
{  
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('score1', 'text', array('label' => **WHAT TO PUT HERE**));
        $builder->add('score2', 'text', array('label' => **WHAT TO PUT HERE**));
    }
}
```

I display all fixtures using this code, and it works great.

**index.html.twig**

```
    {% for fixture in week.form.fixtures %}
        {{ form_widget(fixture) }}
    {% endfor %}
```

Maybe I could customize my labels directly in index.html.twig but how can I get fixtures data?

Does somebody encounter this issue and resolve it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found a solution!

In "index.html.twig" template, I iterated over form elements.
It was a mistake. I just had to iterate over fixtures and get related form widget.

**index.html.twig**

```php
{% for fixture in week.fixtures %}
    fixture.HomeTeam.name
    {{ form_widget(week.form.fixtures[loop.index0]) }}
    fixture.AwayTeam.name
{% endfor %}
```

The trick is to retrieve form elements directly from form widgets array :

```
    week.form.fixtures[loop.index0]
```

Answer (score 0):

http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-each-field-by-hand

use

```
{{ form_label(fixture) }}  <-  {{ team.name }}
{{ form_errors(fixture) }}
{{ form_widget(fixture) }}
```

instead of

```
{{ form_widget(fixture) }}
```