# How to build this type of simple but complex form with symfony forms

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have tried a lot and have not yet able to find solution to this problem. i am not sure if thats possible or not.

I have one table called `Student` then table called `Assigment` and `Solutions`

Now there are questions Stored in Assignment Table which are common to all students. But different student will submit different solutions.

On the form i want to have `label` as Question text and then text box as solution to that question.

IN the beginning i have the empty answers in database.

I am confused how can i use symfony to build this form

Becasue all solutions will be submiited togetehr with one submit button

```
Class AssignmentFormType{

$builder-> add('answer','collection' ....)
```

This is working fine but only thing here i want is to display that QuestionText as label for that Answer and i am not able to find that for 1 week

Comment: Simple *and* complex? Isn't that an oxymoron?

Comment: I said simple because there is only one field in form , complex beacuse i didn't knew how to make it working

Comment: Does http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6726878/symfony2-customize-form-labels-in-form-collections not answer your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to dynamically create a form element based on information from your entity (i.e. setting label = $entity->getQuestion)

Two approaches:

A. Dynamic forms

http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_generation.html

Basically involves setting up a listener then using it to create your form element with access to each individual entity.  Bit of a pain but it works.

B. Inside of the form template

Since all you want to do is to change the label then it might be easier to just set it inside of your form template.  Something like:

```
{{ form_label(form.assignment, form.assignment.vars.value.question) }}
```

The .data should give you the actual assignment entity from which you can pull the question.

Comment: with the second approach , the problem is that id i don't display the question field , then it gets updated to null as it was there in the form but i didn't render it. In the dunamic form totorial i still didn't understand their example on the site. it was just hiding one field based on if its new or not. Can you give me some info how can i find more info on dynamic forms

Comment: Lets stick with approach A first.  Please post your template code for the assignments.

Comment: I tried fist apprach 2-3 days back and i was getting $data as null. s i deleted the code but i will do that now and will post the code here. thanks

Comment: I made a mistake in my original answer.  Use vars.value to grab the entity.